# File not found when reading files from Google colab

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory, filenotfounderror

So I have a program that is creating multiple files in the /content path in my colab session with `f'{directory}/{services}.csv'` with `directory = r'/content'`.

This part works fine and creates all the files without error. However I'm trying to read the csv files I created in the /content path in another function with `pd.read_csv(f'{directory}/{services}.csv')` and whenever I run it, I get a

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/.config.csv'` I don't fully understand the error here, but the code works perfectly in PyCharm when I'm using a regular local pc directory. None of these are files that I upload to colab, but rather files I create inside it. Not sure how colab operates with this kind of thing.